# Is it possible to add a Image to the control collection of the header of RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

I would like to add and Image along with the HeaderText in RadGrid. I can able to do this in ItemBound event. But is there any possible ways to do the same in page prerender event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it worked, here is the code to add the image in pre render event.

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GridHeaderItem headerItem = (GridHeaderItem)RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0];
       Image img = new Image();
       img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Refresh.gif";
       headerItem["FirstName"].Controls.AddAt(1, img);
   }
```

Comment: This works, but I've noticed that some grid events that perform a postback (e.g. OnColumnsReorder) will cause the Image (in this case) to disappear when the postback completes. Adding it during OnItemDataBound makes it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

is possible, but do not know if it's a good idea.

```
((GridHeaderItem)((GridTHead)grid.MasterTableView.Controls[0].Controls[0]).Controls[1]).Cells[2].Text= "Test!"
```

it is good to check the types of controls.